# Connecting Looker to SAS

Tags: sas, looker

Does anyone know if you can connect Looker directly to a SAS table/server? or would you use a work-around to upload the SAS data to a SQL server, then connect Looker to that?

Answer (score 0):

The SAS dataset (analogous to a table) is in a proprietary, binary format. If you have SAS Access to OleDb or ODBC, I would upload the table from SAS and not bother using a SAS format.

You must have SAS Access to upload the dataset from SAS, however, otherwise you are facing how to read a SAS dataset outside of SAS issue. Let us know what you have, in terms of software, so we can help guide a solution.

Comment: Yeah that was kinda my thought.
Though software like Tableau can read SAS directly.
but it seems with Looker I'll need to upload into a SQL DB. I can possibly get access to that.
for Power BI, this is the same, though I have a workaround using R.

Comment: The SAS dataset is ODBC compliant. Download the ODBC client from SAS and read the dataset into PowerBI. I don't know Looker but PowerBI is, no pun intended, a powerhouse right now.

The ODBC method has limitations but that is the approach I would take.